# Почему на сайте zaycev.net html файлу отправляется http запрос?

Tags: php, http

Я не очень силён в веб разработке, мне казалось что запросы можно отправлять только `php` файлам, а в вышеуказанном случае запрос выглядит так

http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=25

Тут в чём-то подвох, или ничего необычного?

Comment: Запросы отправляются на адрес. А в адресе можно хоть mp3 написать - запросы обработаются так, как настроен сервер, можно даже php-скриптом, можно даже если написано mp3. Адрес не имеет никакого отношения к реально существующим файлам на сервере

Comment: ничего необычного.

Comment: @andreymal, и что, тогда в html\mp3 файле php код?

Comment: А еще (внезапно) сайт может быть написан не на php.

Comment: @ArturKlochko файл, который написан в адресе, может вообще не существовать. Ещё раз, адреса не имеют никакого отношения к реально существующим файлам на сервере

Comment: И тут у Артура возник синдром белки)) [без обид]  Теперь Артур возможно захочет разобраться, а как же работает веб-сервер и какие вообще веб-серверы существуют))

Comment: Наклепал демку https://andreymal.org/files_demo/имяфайла.mp3 — какое имя файла ни выбирай, всегда будет срабатывать Python-скрипт, который выдаст html-страничку с именем файла

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Рискну ответить :)

Тут надо понимать как работает `веб-сервер`.

Если в `двух словах` и доступно, то как вы получаете файл или обращаетесь к нему? Вы шлете запрос `http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=25` (сформировав заголовок) и ждете ответ.

Ваш заголовок принимает например `Apache` либо `nginx` либо любой другой веб-сервер. У веб-сервера есть набор инструкций, и грубо говоря он берет ваш заголовок и сравнивает его со своими инструкциями, и в зависимости от этого принимает решение что вам отдать.

Условно говоря, к примеру, веб-сервер видит что вы хотите страницу `http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=25` увидеть. А у него инструкция: если файл `search.html` - то обратиться к файлу `search.php` за ответом. Когда мы говорим о внешних файлах (картинках и т.д.), то можно сказать что у веб-сервера инструкция: мол если на сервере по такому-то пути есть файл, то отдай его. Если какой-то инструкции будет не хватать то вы получите ошибку :<

Манипулируя этими правилами(инструкциями) можно делать много всякой магии, если разберетесь, то в Хогвартс возьмут без вступительных экзаменов ;)